# How to verify new digits of $\pi$?

Tags: algorithms, pi

Bob makes a claim that he made a new record and computed $\pi$ to 10 trillion digits (or your favourite number here). How would Alice verify that the newly computed constant is actually a correct approximation of $\pi$?

> Given a finite string $x,$ of $n+1$ decimal digits: $(3\ 1\ 4\ 1\ 5\ 9\ 2\ldots),$ is there an efficient algorithm to decide whether $x$ is an approximation of $\pi$ up to the $0.\underbrace{00 \ldots 01}_{n-1}$ decimal places?

---

Edit: *Clarification*.

1. Alice does not have access to Bob's method (so she can't prove that his method is correct).
2. Alice only receives $x$ from Bob (in any number bases), and wants to verify that $x$ is indeed a correct approximation. No further communications between them.
3. Alice could look at all digits of $x$ but should be able to verify in time $\ll$ than what it takes to compute $x$.
4. Motivation: Assume [Alexander J. Yee](http://www.numberworld.org/misc_runs/pi-5t/details.html) did not publish his code nor his method. He only publish $x$ in many number bases. He said it took him 3 months to compute $x.$ How could we verify his claims that $x$ is correct in a day or week or two without access to his code and formulas? Is there such a verification formula or algorithm?

Comment: See [Approximations of $\pi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Development_of_efficient_formulae).

Comment: Not sure if this link helps or not. But you may refer this as well http://www.numberworld.org/misc_runs/pi-5t/details.html

Comment: Can you ask Bob to give you the digits in base 16?

Comment: @Aryabhata yes. In any base.

Comment: My earlier link was just silly, but perhaps this one might be useful in the context you are looking for http://tinyurl.com/84396h3

Comment: @J.D.: Would a randomized algorithm do? Otherwise we do need to look at all the trillion digits, which I suppose is not permitted because of the lack of computing power?

Comment: @Aryabhata the randomized algorithm would do for sure.

Comment: I guess I tricked you guys into (1) crypto argument (2) bounded complexity argument. You can look at all the trillion digits, but you should be able to verify $x$ in a time $\ll$ that generating $x$. I'm really thinking here in practical terms. Assume Alexander J. Yee in the link above did not publish his code nor his method. He only publish $x$ in many bases. He said it took him 5 months to compute $x$. How could we verify his claims that $x$ is correct in a day or two without access to his code and formulas? Is there such a verification formula or algorithm?

Comment: Great Question J.D. (Reminds all of us of some clever methods)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you allow any base, (16 in particular) and randomized algorithm, you can use the [Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) formula which allows you to compute the $n^{th}$ digit of $\pi$, without having to compute the earlier $n-1$ digits! (Alas, such a algorithm seems to have been discovered only for base-16.)

All Alice needs to do is pick "some" random digits and compare.

Comment: Fascinating! Classic method discovered in 1995.

Comment: How efficient is it to convert between bases?

Comment: @PyRulez: Not sure what you mean by efficient, but given an n digit number in base b, there will be a linear time algorithm ($\mathcal{O}(n)$) to convert between bases. People are still trying to find such formulae in other bases...

Comment: Check the latest developments. Apparently a similar formula exists in base $10$ since this year.

Comment: @BeniBogosel. Thanks! Will take a look.